# How do i catch bad URL requests using REST easy

Tags: java, jboss, jax-rs, resteasy

I have a few endpoints under "/rest/role/"whatever"

how do i catch bad requests for example "rest/role/dbbhwbhb/wdwdwed

if i use :

```
    @GET
    @Path("/{param}")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Response badURLS() {
        return Response.ok().entity("bad url").build();
    }
```

this catches rest/roles/dfsdfsds but rest/roles/sdsasd/asdad is still not caught. How do I set up a method so if none of my endpoints are hit then return a default message ?

Comment: Um, do you mean a 404? I'm pretty sure JBoss handles that for you.

Comment: it does for complete incorrect urls, although if one of my classes has /role path, then a method has /{id} path then role/1 will run that given method, where as if i use role/hello/bla /bla then this is not caught and throws an exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JBoss approach

- https://docs.jboss.org/jbportal/v2.7.0.B1/referenceGuide/html/errorhandling.html

**RESTeasy approach**

- https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.2.0.GA/userguide/html/ExceptionHandling.html

EDIT

As I sent to you before - second link does the trick.

Given the mapper and structure written in such way:

```
package atata;

import javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider
public class _404Handler implements ExceptionMapper<NotFoundException> {

    public Response toResponse(NotFoundException exception) {
        return Response.status(500).entity(new ResponseEntity(333, "Got 404.")).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
    }

}
```

Config

```
package atata;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;


public class EmployeeApplication extends Application {

    private Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<Object>();

    public EmployeeApplication() {
        singletons.add(new MessageRestService());
        singletons.add(new _404Handler());
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        return singletons;
    }

}
```

Pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>io.atata</groupId>
    <artifactId>atata</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>atata Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-jaxrs -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.19.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-servlet-initializer</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.14.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>atata</finalName>
    </build>
```

Endpoint:

package atata;

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/roles")
public class MessageRestService {

    @GET
    @Path("/1")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response badURLS() {
        return Response.ok().entity("OK").build();
    }

}
```

You will get

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have to write custom exceptions to catch 404 bad requests !!! thats soudns crazy

Comment: What if I want to return something to the user, ie. 'invorrect url"

Comment: 1) Where did you find the obligation to write custom exceptions? There is info about ExceptionMapper. Please take a look at that doc once you get some time.

2) I updated the answer.

Comment: @robm, what's about this question?